# Finite Variety in $\mathbb{C}^5$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $V=V(x_3-x_1^2,x_4-x_1x_3,x_2x_3-x_1x_5,x_4^2-x_3x_5)\subseteq \mathbb{C}^5$ be an affine variety. Is V a finite set of points?

I tried using Groebner bases, but I can not get anywhere. Could someone please help me?

Comment: Do you understand the definition of $V$?

Comment: yes I understand, but only the definition of  V  is enough?

Comment: If you can't tell from the plain definition of $V$ whether or not it's finite, it's hard to tell whether you do understand the definition :).  This is a very simple set of equations.

Comment: I know, I just would like to confirm the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Your question does not indicate this desire.  It reads as if you have no idea where to begin.  Please clarify your question.

Comment: I was wrong at the beginning.Thanks!

Comment: I thought it was more difficult. Excuse me by mistake. I was study Grobner Basis and this problem was on the list.

Comment: I think something in my answer here colud be usefull to you http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/595268/prime-maximal-ideals-of-mathbbcx-y-containing-a-given-ideal/595503#595503

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

You are living in $\mathbb C^5$.

You have **four** equations.

Then what is the minimal dimension your variety can have?